# pass hidden fields as array to jquery to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I've got a small jquery function that allows for uploads and then appends to the form with some hidden fields (for the images) as such:

```
        if(response===""){
                $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').text(file).addClass('error');
            }
            else{
                $('<p></p>').appendTo('#files').html('<img src="./uploads/'+response+'" alt="" /><input type="hidden" id="user_files" name="user_files[]" value="'+response+'"><br />'+'Successfully Uploaded').addClass('success');
            }
```

Then I am catching it within another jquery piece that is like this:

```
  var userfiles = $('#user_files');
```

But this field could hold multiple files that were uploaded - so it could be an array. Right now, it's only catching a single image: userfiles - 1397416395.jpg

How can I make that catch the array?

Comment: If you are receiving a response in an array in JS anyway, there is no need to feed it back to the HTML, and retrieve it again using JS, right? You can just store the array in a variable.

Comment: It's not coming back as an array. At least I don't think so. When I post it over to catch.php it only shows that one file, even tho 2 were uploaded.

Comment: I've tried this: var params['userfiles'] = $("#user_files").val(); var userfiles = params; and that doesn't seem to work

Comment: What is your `response`? We have no idea how your `response` variable is passed and constructed.

Comment: The only thing that is being passed is: userfiles - 1397416395.jpg instead of userfiles - Array. I am not sure how to make it an array.

Comment: No, my question is, how is the value of `response` being constructed at the first place? It must have been either passed from the server, generated by a script or entered by a user, no?

Comment: So the user clicks upload, then selects a file, then it uploads. When it uploads, it returns the file name, and then using jquery it appends a hidden field with an id="user_files" and name="user_files". From there I'd like to pass all the files uploaded to the next jquery portion which is passing it back to another php script

Comment: This line: $('<p></p>').appendTo('#files').html('<img src="./uploads/'+response+'" alt="" /><input type="hidden" id="user_files" name="user_files[]" value="'+response+'"><br />'+'Successfully Uploaded').addClass('success');

Comment: Every time a file is uploaded you create another element `<input type="hidden" id="user_files" name="user_files[]" value="'+response+'">`. I hope you can see the mistake. Use `class` instead of `id` since there should only ONE UNIQUE id on the page. Using jquery you can now catch all files with $('.user_files')